# Once i activate models in django, why can't i query them directly in postgresql pgAdmin UI?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am very new to Django & to web programming in general. So, I apologize for the silly question. I am using django as a framework with python & I have made a connection with my database, Postgresql :

```
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'testdb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

After that I ran the `python manage.py migrate` command & it outputted that everything was OK. I have also created models:

```
class Albums(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class Song(models.Model):
    albums = models.ForeignKey(Albums, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

After that I run the commands `python manage.py makemigrations`, it outputs that it works. Then, I run the command `python manage.py migrate` & it outputs that everything is ok.

I want to know why, when I go to the database in pgAdmin & I query the data with a `SELECT * FROM Albums`, it does not even recognize the relation.

This is probably not the right way to test if the tables were created, but can anyone help me out and tell me why they are not created in the pgAdmin UI as well ?

Also, how can I check to see where the tables are created ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: tables are not created with the exact name of the class, select for all the tables in the db and you'll see they are name like lowercase 'appname_classname'

Comment: @simonecittadini thank you for the help! :) and sorry for the silly question

Comment: @simonecittadini please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table name would be a bit different, it would not be the same as the model name. It would be "app_model". All the characters are lowercase. In this example, your query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM 'app'_albums
```

please replace 'app' with your app name in lower case

As you said, you are new to web development, try

```
\dt *.*
```

This will list all the tables in your database.