# Can't access to django models with an external script

Tags: django, django-models

I have created a Django project with a series of tables (models) using postgresql. The thing, is that one of them I want to be able to access it also from outside the Django project, because from Django I simply want to see its content, but with an external script I want to insert the data.

The problem I have is that when I try to access any of the tables created in django from an external script, the windows terminal, or even the program that postgresql offers. It tells me that the table does not exist. What am I leaving or doing wrong?

The problem I have is that when I try to access any of the tables created in django from an external script, the windows terminal, or even the program that postgresql offers. It tells me that the table does not exist. What am I leaving or doing wrong?

Below I show a screenshot with the tables I have and how it gives me an error.

[image]

As you can see I have the ability to see all the tables, but then it doesn't let me `select` any of them. I have tried everything with lowercase and neither, removing the prefix `Platform_App_` and neither How can I access them?

Here I leave a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41360568/once-i-activate-models-in-django-why-cant-i-query-them-directly-in-postgresql) that was asked similarly but I can't get it to work.

Thank you.

Comment: Idk where your previous similar question gone, but I advice to try this again: `select * from "Platform_App_fleet";`

Comment: It works, sorry and thank you!!

Comment: You know why is happening this?

Comment: Glad to help - I will post more details in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will expend answer to be more clear of why this helped.

Short answer: all identifiers without double-quoting are always folded to lower case in PostgreSQL.

Almost that short answer: the main problem is that your table name uses mixed-case table name. PostgreSQL require using [double-quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) to make identifier case-sensitive.

So, if your table was named as `platform_app_fleet`, then this will work:

```
select * from platform_app_fleet;
```

because table name is in lower case. But when you have table named with mixing lower and upper cases like `Platform_App_fleet` - you need to use quoting:

```
select * from "Platform_App_fleet";
```